# C# Copy DataTable from index[x] to end

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I am loading a dataset from an excel file. I grab the first table as `DataTable table`. I want to return a datatable that starts at the `int startingIndex`. I want to do something like:

```
DataTable table = GetDtFromFile();
DataTable results;
table.Rows.CopyTo(results, startingIndex);
return results;
```

The only solutions for this I see are using for loops to loop through every row after the `startingIndex` and copy rows over individually. This seems silly and unnecessary.

Any tricks out there I'm not seeing on how to do this? Thanks!

---

**Other Attempts:**

```
DataTable table = GetDtFromFile();
DataTable results;
int size = table.Rows.Count - startingRow;
DataRow[] temp = new DataRow[size];
table.Rows.CopyTo(temp, startingRow);
results.Rows = temp;
```

This has an error on results.Rows that DataTable.Rows is read only. (This also seems unnecessarily complicated).

Comment: I see three solutions for this: a) get the table and use a loop to copy the data to the new table b) get the table, clone it (`.Copy()`) and remove the rows before the index and c) use an excel-reading library and only use the data you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you linq!

Answer:

```
DataTable table = GetDtFromFile();
DataTable results;
int startingRow = GetStartingRow();
int size = table.Rows.Count - startingRow;
results = table.AsEnumerable().Skip(startingRow).Take(size).CopyToDataTable();
```